# After configuring Zendesk Keyclock Saml SSO Integration User sing-in is getting We are sorry ..Page Not found when directing to keyclock login

Tags: keycloak, single-sign-on, saml, zendesk

I use Keyclocak 23.0.3 SAML SSO with Zendesk , I configured the client setting in the realm and so on
The server has : certfication is not valid btw

SAML SSO URL=
https://myserver/auth/realms/newrealm/protocol/saml

Certificate fingerprint
38cbcba22bd377ac.....

every time user hit sign-in it redirected to keycloak page but gets Page not found

I saw someone tried to remove auth from the above URL when i do it I got Invalid request !!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.